# Extracting project file from delphi.exe

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have all the files needed to open the unit and code but I can't make any changes or compile because the Project.dproj and Project.dpr files are missing. However, I have the .exe file. Is there any way by which the aforementioned files can be extracted from the .exe file?

Comment: Where did you get the .pas files from?

Comment: Just create a project from scratch, usually *.dpr content is stereotypic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have all of the source files, meaning the .pas and .dfm files, then the first thing I'd do is add them all into a new project and try to compile it. It'll either work, meaning you've got everything you need, or it will generate errors.

There would be three kinds of errors:

The first is the most likely -- the forms might use components that you don't have installed. This will be obivous if you try to open the forms in the IDE. If they open without fanfare, GREAT! If you get a warning box saying "Cannot locate component: remove references to it?" or something like that, then you're probably hosed.

The second is version-specific errors -- stuff that's old and crufty and no longer supported by the language.

Third, the program may use run-time libraries that you don't have.

Comment: Hi there , i am new to delphi , can you please suggest in mac in which software i can open .dpr files ?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler adds RTTI metadata, including unit names, when it builds, and if you know about how the RTTI tables are laid out it's possible to extract this.  The unit list is the principal component of the DPR file, but it takes some serious work to access it and I'm not aware of any tools out there that read the RTTI tables that have been kept up to date beyond the Delphi 7 era.

As for the .dproj file, you're out of luck.  That doesn't actually contain any code that gets "compiled in" to the EXE; it's a set of build instructions for how to produce the EXE.  But if the Delphi IDE doesn't have one, it can generate a default .dproj from the .dpr, if you can produce that.

I'm curious, though.  How did you obtain the .pas files but not the .dpr?